# Android - DrawerLayout set background for another side

Tags: android, android-layout

I create DrawerLayout with ListView. When I swipe menu I see this menu, but another side still white. I wanna change backgroun color when Drawer open and change it color when move navigation from left to right like in Gmail or Play market.

[image]

My **activity**

```js
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

  DrawerItemObject[] drawerListItems = {
    new DrawerItemObject("Las news"),
    new DrawerItemObject("MEG")
  };
  drawerList.setAdapter(new DrawerItemAdapter(this, R.layout.left_drawer_listview_item_row,     drawerListItems));
  drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

**setScrimColor** not work

And **activity_layout**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: If the content isn't dimming when you open the drawer (if that is indeed what you're referring to), then you might not have your layout setup correctly. Please post the `activity_main` layout.

Comment: I find solution

Answer (score 2):

In my **activity_main** layout I forgot add

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >

    <!-- Add FrameLayout -->
    <!-- NEW CODE STRART-->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <!-- NEW CODE END-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: If you're going to answer this question rather than delete it, then you need to include the relevant part of the problem in the question, and show exactly what you did to solve it in the answer. As it is now, future users aren't going to know what you're talking about, or how "forgot add `<FrameLayout>`" fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> **setScrimColor**
>
> void setScrimColor (int color) Set a color to use for the scrim that
>   obscures primary content while a drawer is open.
>
> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setScrimColor(int)